# Importing sql data into solr using the data handler called from C#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2013, solr

I'm trying to call the data import handler in solr to import records from sql into a solr collection, I've got the request the ui sends from fiddler, and I am using the same request in my c# application, however the request does not import the data. Can anyone help me get this working?

```
public class SolrRequest
    {
        public string SendPostRequest(string requestType, string dataToPost, string requestInfo, string pathOfRequest)
        {


            LocalhostSet.LocalhostSet solrlocalhost = new LocalhostSet.LocalhostSet();
            string hasSuccess = "";
            string localhostSet = "";
            localhostSet = solrlocalhost.setLocalHost(localhostSet);
            string URI = "http://localhost:8999/solr/new_core/dataimport" ;
            string myParameters = "full-import&clean=true&commit=true&wt=json&indent=true&entity=holidays&rows=10000000&verbose=false&optimize=false&debug=false";
            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, myParameters);
            }
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(requestInfo);
               var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(localhostSet);
                request.Method = requestType;
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

                if (requestType.Equals("PUT") | requestType.Equals("POST"))
                {
                    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
                    {
                        writer.Write(dataToPost);
                    }
                }
               HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                hasSuccess = "Request Successful";
                string status = response.StatusDescription.ToString();
                if (requestType.Equals("GET"))
                {
                 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                    string tmp = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            catch (WebException webex)
            {
                WebResponse errResp = webex.Response;
                using (Stream respStream = errResp.GetResponseStream())
               {
                 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(respStream);
                    string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                hasSuccess = "Request Unsuccessful";
            }
            Console.WriteLine(hasSuccess);
            return hasSuccess;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The url was wrong, the url should reference the collection in this case "new_core"

http://localhost:8999/solr/new_core/dataimport?command=full-import